# Capitalizing the first word in each sentence

Tags: c++

I need to make a program that capitalizes the first character of each sentence in a string. For instance, if the string argument is “hello. my name is Joe. what is your name?” the function should manipulate the string so it contains “Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?” I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void capitalize(char sentence[], int const SIZE);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 1024;
    char sentence[SIZE];

    cout << "Enter a string:  " << endl << endl;
    cin.getline(sentence, SIZE);

    capitalize(sentence, SIZE);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}

void capitalize(char sentence[], int SIZE)
{

     char *strPtr;
     int count = 0;

     sentence[0] = toupper(sentence[0]);

     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     {
         strPtr = strstr(sentence[i], ".");

         if (*strPtr == '.')
         {
                     *strPtr = toupper(*strPtr);
         }
     }

     while (sentence[count] != '\0')
     {
          cout << sentence[count];
          count++;
     }
}
```

Comment: What's the output your code produces?

Comment: @Fallen I get an error message saying that 'strstr' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Some tips: 1) Decide whether you are writing C or C++. 2) Looping until you reach SIZE will most likely go past the end of what the user inputs.

Comment: @PAXlater You need to include `cstring`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstring> // need this for strstr()

void capitalize(char sentence[], int SIZE)
{

     char *strPtr;
     int count = 0;

     sentence[0] = toupper(sentence[0]);

     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     {
         strPtr = strstr(&sentence[i], ".");
         //strPtr returns the pointer to 
         //the first occurence of "." after sentence[i]
        if(strPtr==NULL) break;
         if (*strPtr == '.') 
         {
            // you really dont want to do this
            //*strPtr = toupper(*strPtr); 
            // put the suitable code here and everything will work
         }
     }
    //why the while loop? and count?
     while (sentence[count] != '\0')
     {
          cout << sentence[count];
          count++;
     }
}
```

What you were doing was to capitalize "." but clearly you want the next character to be capitalized. So write that part of code yourself as you'll find it more rewarding.

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentioned in the comments, you're not including `cstring`. Second, you're calling `strstr` on `sentence[i]`, which is a char. You want `sentence + i` which is a char*. That'll fix your syntax errors.

For logical error, it looks like you're trying `toupper` the period.

`strPtr = strstr(sentence[i], ".");` should find the first period in the string starting at `i` (inclusive). Then you check if `strstr` found anything (if not it would return null. If it's found the sequence you uppercase `strPtr`, but `strPtr` still points at the first character of the target string, that is `'.'`. You should be looking for the target string `". "` then incrementing one past that to find the first letter of the next sentence. Unfortunately there's no safe way of doing that with `strstr` since it doesn't tell you how far into the string it looked, so it's possible the string simply ends with `". "` and one past that falls off the array. You're either going to need to iterate through the array manually, looking for `'.'` then checking past that, or use `std::find` instead.